# Is there a way to give an if statement for a date to be disabled if start & end date are the same?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, calendar

This is a calendar booking system, I have a bug that if i book for a single day it books for the following day also. The solution i believe is to have a statement where if both start/end date is the same, then book both slots.

However i am struggling to write this in the right format.

```
function wpkGetThisDateSlots(date) {
  var slots = {
    isFirstSlotTaken: false,
    isSecondSlotTaken: false,
  };

  if (typeof disabledDates !== 'undefined') {
    if (wpkIsDateInArray(date, wpkStartDates)) {
      slots.isFirstSlotTaken = slots.isSecondSlotTaken = true;
      return slots;
    }
    if (typeof disabledDates !== 'undefined') {
      if (wpkIsDateInArray(date, wpkEnddate)) {
        slots.isFirstSlotTaken = slots.isSecondSlotTaken = true;
        return slots;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried formatting the start date and end date so that if the same date is selected. Disable the date. However I understand that logically wouldn't work.

```
  if (typeof Startdate == typeof Enddate )
```

or

```
if (slots.Firstslottaken == slots.Secondslottaken) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As dates are objects in JavaScript, using the equality operator (`==`) will test whether both variables refer to the same instance of an object.

In your case, this isn't what you want; rather, you want to test whether both objects refer to the same date/time.

First of all, you'll probably want to reference this function...

```
function isDateValid(date) {
    return date instanceof Date && !isNaN(date.valueOf());
}
```

The solution depends upon how exact you want to test - do you want the time included? If so...

```
return isDateValid(dateTime1) && dateTime1.getTime() === dateTime2.getTime();
```

If you only want to test the date...

```
return isDateValid(dateTime1) && dateTime1.toDateString() === dateTime2.toDateString();
```

So as an example, if you want to determine whether `dateTime1` is the day before `dateTime2`...

```
function getNextDay(date) {
    // getTime(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime
    // Date constructor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#time_value_or_timestamp_number
    var clonedDate = new Date(date.getTime());
    clonedDate.setDate(clonedDate.getDate() + 1);
    return clonedDate;
}

function isSameDay(date1, date2) {
    return isDateValid(dateTime1) && dateTime1.toDateString() === dateTime2.toDateString();
}

function isDayBefore(date1, date2) {
    if (!isDateValid(date1) || !isDateValid(date2)) {
        return false;
    }
    
    var dayAfterDate1 = getNextDay(date1);
    
    return isSameDay(dayAfterDate1, date2);
}
```

Something else you should keep in mind is the time offset. This may not matter if you're doing everything client-side, but if you're sending date/time objects from the server, ensure that the timezone is included.

Comment: `dateTime1.toDateString() === dateTime2.toDateString()` will return true if both dates are invalid. ;-)

Comment: how would i be able to write: if start date and end date are next to each other make end date false?